# Wireless Connection Issue with rt2800usb dongle 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ralink, wpa-supplicant

I have been having issues connecting to Wi-Fi using a wireless dongle with the rt3572 chip-set. I am running Kubuntu 17.04 kernel version 4.10.0-19, the driver version for the rt2800usb is 2.3.0.

When trying to authenticate manually with

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlxc83a35c729f3 -c wifi_auth
```

I get the following error

```
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlxc83a35c729f3 disable_11b_rate=0
wlxc83a35c729f3: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

I have tried using network-manager and when I look in the Journald log I see the "link is not ready" and that "deauth to the driver failed".

I have also reinserted the rt2800usb module resulting in no error by running the following commands.

```
modprobe -rfv rt2800usb
modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You are correct my friend, it is the RT3572 chipset, which is supported under the rt2800usb driver.
USB device ID: 3572
Vendor ID: 148f

Comment: I am wondering if there has been regression for this driver since I used this device in the past on the 4.8 kernel and it worked fine.